# Using knockout.js to handle data behind jQuery Mobile ajax page transitions

Tags: jquery-mobile, knockout.js

I have a proof-of-concept that is thoroughly and utterly broken here:

http://jsfiddle.net/floyd_may/FAmxj/

I'm hoping the intent behind this is evident. Basically, I want to use `#editPage` to edit elements on `#mainPage` one at a time. However, as soon as you click the 'Back to Main Page' button, the main page is empty.

Can I get some guidance here as to how to make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the `pageinit` event instead of `pagebeforeshow`: http://jsfiddle.net/FAmxj/11/

With `pagebeforeshow`, multiple models are bound to `#mainpage`.

Comment: Your fiddle doesn't work; the changes made on the edit page aren't reflected on the main page.

Comment: However, the `pageinit` event does appear to work; here's the update proof-of-concept:
http://jsfiddle.net/floyd_may/FAmxj/12/
Thanks!